# How can I access a property of a page in a ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code that creates a ViewModel for the page. However in the Viewmodel I want to access the property correctButtonPressed but it's not available.

How can I access this?

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame
{
    public int correctButtonPressed;
    public PhrasesFrameViewModel vm = new PhrasesFrameViewModel();
    public PhrasesFrame() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string abc()
    {
        var a = correctButtonPressed;
    }


}

public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty
{
    private ICommand bButtonClickedCommand;
    public ICommand BButtonClickedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return bButtonClickedCommand ??
                (bButtonClickedCommand = new Command(() =>
                {
                    // Next line gives an error "use expression body for accessors" "use expression body for properties.
                    correctButtonPressed = 123;
                }));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Expose it as a property on the view model and have the view set it.

Comment: @Nkosi - can you explain what you mean maybe with an example.  I'm sorry I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: I'll need more details. The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: I think the property should be on the ViewModel, not on the page (as per architecture of MVVM).

Comment: correctButtonPressed used to be a static property that was part of App.  However I am thinking it should be in the PhrasesFrame as that's the only place it is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expose it as a property on the view model and have the view access it.

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame {

    public PhrasesFrameViewModel vm = new PhrasesFrameViewModel();
    public PhrasesFrame() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string abc() {           
        //View can access correctButtonPressed via the view model.
        var a = vm.correctButtonPressed;
    }
}

public class PhrasesFrameViewModel : ObservableProperty {
    public int correctButtonPressed;

    private ICommand bButtonClickedCommand;
    public ICommand BButtonClickedCommand {
        get {
            return bButtonClickedCommand ??
                (bButtonClickedCommand = new Command(() => {
                    correctButtonPressed = 123;
                }));
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: If I do this how can I access correctButtonPressed in the PhrasesFrame?  I added to the question a small one line method to show what I mean. Thanks

Comment: It was suggested to me that I should maybe pass in a reference (this) to the PhrasesFrame into the view model, add a constructor to the ViewModel and then use that reference to do something like parentFrame.correctButtonPressed = 123 . Do you think this would also be a good alternative?

Comment: @Alan2 that is more a matter of preference. I prefer to not have the View model aware of the view or too tightly coupled to it. The view will have access to members exposed by the view model, all while the view model knows nothing about the view accessing it.